# User making edits that aren't edits

Tags: support, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

We have a user who keeps making edits that actually change nothing. He's just cutting and pasting the code in an attempt to get the edit points.

The user in question is [omiel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2608009/omiel) and here are some example edits:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5006610
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5006563
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5006582

Is it possible to stop this user from making edits?

Comment: The user is adding syntax *highlighting hints*. These are **not** merely cut-and-paste edits (which would not work anyway).

Comment: 2 out of 3 of those edits where rejected anyway, if he keeps this up he'll eventually get banned.

Comment: The user is keeping it up, and the reviewers aren't doing anything about it. He has 44 edit suggestions approved, and 4 edit suggestions rejected, so it doesn't look like he's getting banned in the near future. Seems like its time I hit the suggested edits queue...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The user is adding syntax *highlighting hints*. These are **not** merely cut-and-paste edits (which would not work anyway, there is a minimum amount that needs to have changed before an edit suggestion can enter the system).

Make sure you look at the *markdown diff* as well as the difference in rendered output:

[image: markdown diff]

It is always a good idea to check both views; link changes are hard to detect otherwise, for example, you don't want a spammer sneak in a nefarious link with a innocuous looking edit.

Edits like these *may* be rejected when they are too minor; e.g. if this is the only thing the user edited and left other problems in place. If the user receives enough such edits then they'll automatically receive a (temporary) ban.

Certainly, going around and editing *only* to put in syntax highlight hints *is not very useful* and I'd reject any such edits.

Comment: Ah, didn't see the difference until I looked in the markdown. And I didn't know there was automatic temporary banning. Still fairly new at this reviewing bit. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: The suggestion wouldn't even be submittable without an actual change of at least six characters, @Styphon -- and that excludes whitespace.

Comment: I don't make that kind of edit, but frankly I'd let them through because syntax highlighting can be helpful for readability, and makes it way easier to visually anchor where important things are happening (e.g. function definitions, stack variable allocations, heap variable allocations, explicit casts).