# Removing reputation for rejected edits

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues, suggested-edits, reputation

Bad edits are a perennial topic here. I bring them up myself fairly frequently because the problem seems to be getting worse. I feel that our reputation model is partially to blame: at the +2 rep per edit rate, many users are simply making small and meaningless changes (with my personal "favorite" being `backticking` words that sound even slightly `technical` or **bolding the vital part of the question**) for the reputation, instead of actually taking the time to improve a post properly.

We have a review process to temporarily suspend poor editors, but many reviewers are lazy and the penalty seems to kick in too rarely to act as an effective deterrent against useless edits. More importantly, the measures against bad editors happen late: you have to commit an entire spree of poor edits before getting your first ban. I think the editors should have a more immediate form of feedback, and therefore I suggest placing a -1 or -2 reputation penalty on each rejected edit suggested by the user.

I think a small penalty like that is appropriate. It's not large enough to discourage productive editors from editing in fears of getting rejected, but it's an immediate reminder to the editor, and ought to encourage people regularly making careless edits to be more careful and thorough in the future.

Comment: @kviiri Well honestly, I agree with you. In fact, I even suggested this recently (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267071/3401018), however no one exactly explained to me why this was a bad idea...

Comment: @kviiri the other day I have edited a question, the code was inside block quote instead of proper code block and the edit has been rejected, the reason was too minor edit which I totally disagreed with it. Why should I lose rep because of misjudgement?

Comment: -1 because sometimes edit collisions happen making a suggested edit look strange. If a 2k+ user fixes 5 problems with a post and a suggested edit fixes 4 of them, it will appear like the suggested edit introduces a bad change. These need to be rejected but the user shouldn't be punished for it.

Comment: @mohacs, so you could get a fair feedback for any mistakes you make instead of getting a seemingly random ban after making dozens of unconstructive edits. Getting rep-hounding editors to be more careful would make the work easier for reviewers as well (and thus reduce the amount of bad calls they make).

Comment: @Stijn, I think a better edit conflict system is a technical issue that would need to be handled anyway.

Comment: @Stijn, thanks. I understand the point though, I'm very frustrated with the edit conflicts myself. I just don't have a clear picture of how it's supposed to work, lacking experience with this kind of VC myself.

Comment: Another case, after awhile a question posted OP edited question and added a sentence on top of the question in bold saying __"39 views and still no answer?"__. Deleted that part from question and submitted to review q and I has rejected. Misjudgement again. Kinda agree with you, people just edit posts to change "I'll" to "I will". For my account I am only fixing code indents because I am thinking it is important. How we are going to distinguish which one proper which not.

Comment: @mohacs, misjudgements happen, and that's bad. There are even review audits that have been wrongly labeled, causing people to get banned from reviewing. These can be reported and fixed, and so I believe the reject penalties if they're "awarded" in error. In any case, I believe that any careful editor would get misjudged only occasionally, and the reputation loss would be insignificant while cutting a great deal of unconstructive editing.

Comment: I would be ok with that, as long as it knows the difference between actually-rejected edits, and those that were "rejected" by Community because another edit occurred simultaneously. I have a dozen or two rejected edits, of which I believe most of them were that type.

Comment: I disagree with this suggestion.  It would be better if the +2 rep were removed if the approved suggestion is rolled back.

Comment: -1 This accomplishes nothing except to deter people from wanting to edit in the first place. There are already forms of deterrence that work better (the suspension of privileges). It also would have very limited effectiveness; the +2 rep for edits stops once you've reached a certain amount of rep for doing so, and then you're simply subtracting rep from people who may be honestly trying to improve the question and just not quite understand when and how to do so.

Comment: @KenWhite, I *want* to deter people from editing. Specifically people who routinely make bad edits. You say people don't understand they're making - then why not tell them like we tell people their questions and answers are bad, or off-topic? Currently the site gives absolutely zero feedback to them, and the suspension of privileges happens only late and for opaque reasons. I want a form of immediate, concrete feedback.

Comment: I'd also like to point out that giving negative reputation hasn't been deterring people from answering posts, or at least haven't made us suffer from the lack of answers.

Comment: Are there actually even edits that get rejected? I cant remember anymore if there was a time where rejecting an edit would not pop up the "this edit has already been approved" box. But then again, I stopped doing any reviews a while ago...

Comment: Harder restrictions and lower limits for review-ban should keep the "vampire reviewers" at bay, or at lest decrease the regularity their appearance. PS. Read as "`backtickLing` words"

Comment: @MarcusWigert, yep - but I think the key is *immediate* feedback. No edit ban days after a spree, but rather an immediate notifier that the edit wasn't accepted.

Comment: The only option I can think of would be to let one edit *cost* 1 rep. If it is accepted, one receives +3 rep, giving him a total of +2. Otherwise, he has lost 1 rep. This could at least prevent people from "harvesting" reputation with hundreds of useless edits, and force them to really *think* about which edits will most likely be accepted. (I guess something similar was already proposed somewhere, but I did not find something with a quick search)

Comment: Edits are only reviewed if the user has a low rep anyway. On the other hand, regardless of how low the rep is, nothing stops a user from suggesting new edits. So the suggestion is a bit pointless. If a user really edits for rep points, (s)he will finally reach a rep level where edits gain no rep points at all…

Comment: @Holger, the problem is not that people edit for rep points, it's that people make bad edits, and rep points reward that. And then they get to be reviewers, and start approving bad edits to get a badge.

Comment: @kviiri: I thought you get rep points for *approved* edits only. By making rejected edits you cannot become reviewer. And in the case bad edits are approved your suggestion doesn’t help anyway.

Comment: @Holger, yes, you only get rep for approved edits - but with our sloppy reviewers, you're going to get even minor, "robo-edits" accepted, I don't know, maybe 50% of the time. You get a better "return of investment" for your time by making a ton of little edits than paying real attention to a few edits.

Comment: @KenWhite **This accomplishes nothing except to deter people from wanting to edit in the first place.** I disagree.  This deters *low-rep users* from submitting edits for approval that have a *significant chance of being rejected*.  So many edits are accepted today that it's unlikely that *good edits* will start being rejected, and after enough rep, users can make whatever edits they want.

Comment: I've corrected code before only for it to be rejected by the poster. Why should I be punished as I only have a small score

Comment: I really contemplated bolding "I suggest placing a -1 or -2 reputation penalty on each rejected edit suggested by the user". I restrained myself.

Comment: This will only stop some of the bad edits as it will do nothing to users with 2K+ rep who do not need to get edits approved.

Comment: Suggestion that might reduce possible conflicts and help your suggestion to get approved: make the -1 rep only when the decision of rejecting is unanimous and it has 3 reviewers revisions. Usually, unanimous decisions (for rejecting) do really mean it is a bad edit.

Comment: Reviewer approval is key - don't approve pointless edits. I've had ~30% of my edits rejected and nearly all of them had nothing to do with the quality of work editing. In several cases my edits were superseded by someone with 2k even when my edits were substantially better in improving the material (i.e. capitalize the title and remove extra words compared with clarifying the body of the question).

Answer (score 117):

The problem is that bad edits *are being approved*.  When the bad edits are being approved adding a penalty to having edits rejected won't help.

In fact, it's likely to just make things worse.  You can bet that if there were even more negative repercussions for a rejected edit even less reviewers would be inclined to reject all but the worst suggested edits.  I imagine this would result in a radically reduced number of rejected edits, and much more approved low quality edits.

Comment: we're lacking ways to [educate editors](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237316/227881) as much as reviewers on what is a good edit.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau If bad edits were actually rejected that would educate editors.  They're not learning what's right and wrong because the wrong things are being approved/rejected.

Comment: I agree, generally it's that way but sometime editors are close to make all their edits great ones. Banning them is harsh while a warning could have been enough.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau The problem is that nothing is happening to the bad editors at all because *their bad edits are being approved, not rejected*.  Until *that* problem is solved any adjustments in the consequences of rejected edits cannot possibly change anything.

Comment: @Servy, unless a user is paying very close attention to their suggested edits they won't even know their edit was rejected. There's no feedback to them, unless they actively look it up. And these people eventually wind up being reviewers, without ever learning to edit properly themselves.

Comment: It's likely to make things worse, but also likely to make things better, because the sole possibility that an editor will lose reputation if by any, even very small chance, their edit will be rejected should make people to be more careful when suggesting edits.

Comment: I was so down for the idea of -2 for rejected edits until I read your answer. You're right, this doesn't solve the root issue of bad edits being approved.

Comment: I'd much rather see a -100 to the reviewers who approved a bad edit when it gets rolled back.

Comment: @Servy my bad edits were rejected. I am glad too. When I think about them, they were either wrong or silly, and I didn't realize it until later. So now, I hold off before editing, to provide myself a sanity check. Or I provide my edit as a comment rather than an actual edit.

Comment: @R.., that's a horrible idea. There's one way to get a -100 rep penalty, and that's getting *six* offensive/spam flags. Compare that to rollback, which can be made by a *single* editor. Penalties that a single user can hand out should be no greater than what they already are; a few points of rep.

Comment: @kviiri: Perhaps "-100" is excessive, but I think there should be a serious penalty for approving bad edits, which can easily end up turning a good answer into dangerous mis-advice. If you're not qualified to review the content of the edit, you should be skipping it, and there should be repercussions for not doing so.

Comment: @R..: That seems very problematic. While it's unfortunately much more common for bad edits to be approved, I also see it quite regularly that good edits get rejected. So if I approve a good edit, but 3 others reject it because they either did not look closely or did not understand what was being edited, I will get punished? No thanks. That would stop me from doing edit reviews quickly. Trying to do a thorough job with reviews is thankless work with no personal gain already, and getting penalties for doing it would be the end of it for me.

Comment: Is there any way to confirm this? I mean, it's natural for bad edits to get approved and for good edits to get rejected, but how much of the time is this happening, in comparison to bad edits getting rejected and good edits getting removed? I want to think that even if a penalty is created for bad edits, the person reviewing said edit isn't going to think "If I reject this edit, the person on the other end will lose reputation, therefore I shouldn't do it." I... just don't see that being human nature over the Internet.

Comment: @Zhouster Downvotes have clearly demonstrated that this *is* the case though.  So many people are so vary unwilling to downvote all but the worst of the worst posts, and many say that this is because of the effects that they have on reputation, however small they are.

Comment: @Servy I mean, isn't there a natural stigma to avoid downvoting because it also hurts you? So you have to really think about whether or not you want to downvote something. I'm not sure if the same would apply to edit votes.

Comment: @Zhouster Downvotes only cost rep on answers, not on questions.

Comment: @Servy Ah, I see. Was not aware of that difference. Well, I think it'd still be good to have some hard numbers to back these claims. Questions and edits seem like they would be slightly different as well, just in terms of content variance.

Answer (score 77):

The solution seems straightforward: do not reward people with the +2 rep for editing.

Most people want to make edits because they want to improve the content.  Most of those will likely continue to do so with or without the +2 rep.  I suspect those who are hunting the +2 are strongly correlated with terrible edits.

Comment: Agreed. I'm not sure if I even knew that editing was rewarded with reputation - it has no effect on whether or not I edit someone's answer.

Comment: @SteveBennett: Editing isn't.  Only having a suggested edit approved is rewarded, and you no longer suggest edits.

Comment: Huh, how...odd.

Comment: Why not start with +1 rep for editing, and analyze how that affects editing and reviewing activities?

Comment: I [wouldn't care](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252989/241211) about the +2 if I could already make edits without review. Some edits I have made were minor. Some edits I _wanted to make but didn't_ would have been minor. If I was at 2k, I'd have the same feeling as @SteveBennett: making edits because they _should_ be made, but since I am not, I have to weigh whether an edit would be rejected (to date, none have been).

Comment: To be honest, I find the whole approach of tying everything to reputation weird and unappealing. To me, editing answers is not a privilege, it's a necessary task. If I was designing SO, I'd let anyone with say 100 rep edit other people's answers, provide feedback mechanisms and guidance, and block people from editing if they misuse it.

Comment: @Steve: If I were going to make a change, it would be that if the post author has more than 2k rep, for 48 hours the edit goes to the author for review.  After that it can be applied or reviewed depending whether the post prior to edit has more than 5 upvotes.  This would make it really easy for low rep users to help fix problems of new users, while preventing damage to valuable content (content which is upvoted by the community or written by an author with many other upvotes is assumed to be valuable).

Comment: Agree 100% - but I also think we should remove badges for reviewing edits as well. Un-gamify the problem areas.

Comment: I'm with Michael. The only reason I care about reputation is because it would make it easier to make edits. I'm just starting in the tech field so I don't have a lot of technical knowledge, but I'm pretty good at proofreading and I would like to contribute to the site in the way that I can.

Comment: @Kirk Woll. I like this, but if I am the submitter of a question, and someone does an edit I really like, I would like to have the option of maybe granting them 2 of my reputation points as a reward for helping me. This way edits that don't really do anything for me may be accepted, but not rewarded, and good ones are motivated to continue.

Comment: @Brian, I'm not sure you understand how the rep bonus works.  It will be awarded quite independently of any action on your part.  *Others* have to approve it in the edit queue (the odds of it being you is slim).  However, as this whole question illustrates, bad edits are getting through, and that must stop.  IMO, people *want* to edit; the fact we are giving people the option to edit *at all* (rather than depending on their obtaining 2000 rep) albeit with some extra moderation, is *already an awesome privilege*.  I see absolutely no reason we need to gild the lily and also award reputation.

Comment: Yes! I didn't even know until now that there was a reward for accepted edits and I have edited questions with good will several times. I think this would be perfect.

Comment: @KirkWoll, I understand. You may not realize what I am suggesting is a whole new way to look at rep vs edits. Start using rep as a currency, that is spent by the people approving the edits. They will think twice. Then the edits that are truly worth while will get submitted through. It is a simple practice of positive and negative initiative. Think of rep as cash in an economy.

Comment: @Brian, are you *seriously* suggesting that people *spend* their rep in order to exercise their voluntary charity of helping approve edits!?!?

Comment: @KirkWoll, yes. But only by the amount that they want to contribute to the editor. So if the edit means nothing, then I contribute nothing. If the edit is amazing, then I contribute how much I feel like it is worth to me. But editors that contribute nothing of value get nothing of value for their contribution. So we are discouraging useless contributions and approvals become tips from the approver to the editor. Tips work in every other industry, why not here?

Comment: @KirkWoll, we already use rep as an economy here, so all I am saying is expand that to edit approvals. Just not mandatory, but as a tip, set by the approver, that way we don't need the +2 on quick or mindless approvals.

Comment: But the edit reputation is almost the only way a new user can gain reputation and keep it. If I got reputation removed for my edits that have been rejected, I would probably still be stuck at ~50 rep.

Comment: Along with those people that spuriously reject edits to their own questions...

Answer (score 50):

I think instead of going for all out `-2` to all rejections (which will make people less likely to reject) or all out removal of the `+2` for accepted edits, we should give the reviewers an opportunity to rate the edit's reputation value.

Make the default no rep change.  Have a slider with 5 steps from "vandalism" to "neutral" to "great edit" by which outstandingly positive or negative edits can be given rep changes by the reviewers.  (The actual change is the average given by reviewers).

That way there is a way to accept good-but-minor edits without giving an incentive to spam them.  And it stays safe to reject questionable edits, while also having a tool for fighting back against atrocious ones.

And the robo-reviewers probably won't be bothered to change the rating, because they're mostly interested in their own review count.

Statistical data could also reveal voting rings in a way that isn't possible from a simple accept/reject vote.

Note: If the accept or reject button is clicked contrary to the rating, the reviewer will get a popup error.

Comment: Just have the slider be `off` by default, forcing reviewer to rate the edit... take that robo-reviewers!

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau: No, I specifically want giving rep to require more clicks than accepting with no rep.  Robo-reviewers will do the minimum amount of work as always, and I don't want that minimum to include a rep award.

Comment: Forcing them to do one more click might dissuade some robo-reviewer to keep doing it... but I see your point.

Comment: Vote rings aren't just "this is abuse" and "these are just good happy users". Knowing a user, for example, can subconsciously introduce bias.

Comment: @bjb568: My vote may be influenced by a user's previously demonstrated level of expertise... but a particular user isn't going to be a significant fraction of my reviews, or even reviews granting rep, not the way it would be for sockpuppets.  And by making the "usual" action to accept with no rep given, funny business should stand out more.

Comment: @BenVoigt How about a group of users in chat (for an event or something), where half the edits in the queue are from them? You go "meh, -1", "ok, 0", "great, BobbyTables is a good editor, +2", without even realizing it.

Comment: At the very least I really like the idea of an extra click or two beyond reject/approve, to also say "this is a worthwhile edit -- someone not only spent some time cleaning this up, they did it really well, too!", while leaving the default at no rep change (for the cases when someone just changes "I'll" to "I will" or vice versa - maybe reject, maybe approve something like that, but don't penalize them by default). I'd like a 3 position scale from 0-2 rep (0 default), with a vote of "Vandalism" that doesn't penalize instantly (not unless/until they do it several times, by banning or rep hit)

Comment: I agree with this answer. If both "bounds" are troublesome, give a *middle-position* solution, and **this answer** is the one I was thinking about. Upvoted :).

Comment: @bjb: They won't see the same review items.  And even if they did, their reviews are spread over a larger number of editors.  The funny business is the pattern where a small set of reviewers is awarding rep to a small set of editors.

Comment: @BenVoigt So it's a negligible effect? Well, at least, there should be a system for checking abuse... I think this is needlessly complex. If no rep is awarded every time, it would be like a mod task, which is fitting since it is. Like all mod tasks, there is no positive feedback, only negative: bans.

Comment: @bjb568: The effect is not negligible if it is repeated often enough...  Remember you can review edits without going through the queue if you have a link to the post...

Answer (score 9):

As a person who edits posts in StackOverflow, I'd like to state my priorities while editing a post.

1. Re-tagging - AFAIC, it seems like a big deal. Personally, while I am searching for a solution on SO, the first thing I do is a tag filtering. So the first thing I do while I encounter with a post which is not tagged relevantly, is re-tag it.
2. Serious spelling/grammatical mistakes.
3. Questions without proper title.
4. The code which is not `coded` and unformatted external links.

For me anything which comes under the four mentioned above is a valid edit and I'd like to do it whether or not I'm awarded with a +2 reputation. IMHO It's not proper to add/remove our own sentences and code to someone else's post in extensive manner. If that seems necessary, I prefer to flag it or comment for more details.

Personally, I'd like to second [**Kirk Woll**'s suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267343/1230782). Because sometimes I had a feeling that some of the reviewers rejecting the edits (which contains at least one of the above 4) because it's not worth a +2 rep.

Comment: I would suggest that you're missing the big point of editing with that list.  The #1 'big deal' should be fixing questions that are not good questions, grammar or spelling aside: where the question does contain a nugget of good question, but is too badly written or organized to be a good question; missed a lot of information which later ended up in comments; the initial question was off topic (asking for a tool, for example) but could be converted into a useful question.  These are the most important edits.  Everything in your list is second tier.

Comment: When you've rejected over 400 edits as vandalism because they only "improve formatting" by not touching formatting and doing 1 (tagging java as jQuery), 2 (editing correct english into... what's on the front page), 3 (adding tags to the title), *or* 4 (backticking random words), you find that the list isn't that good. What should happen is: a) remove thanks b) put the (one, else don't edit and CV too broad) question in a visible spot c) make a fitting (else CV unclear) title based on it d) add code from an external link e) remove irrelevant code and f) remove ***misuse*** of 1. `formatting`.

Answer (score 3):

"Rejected edits" don't deserve down-votes. Someone has made an effort to edit it, if it isn't good its rejected. If an edit is good then they get accepted and a +2 is given for users below 2000 rep, that's a good practice to keep up good edits.

When too many edits are rejected the user is automatically banned from edits for a period, this keeps a check on bad edits.

Well there are exceptions but I think the current system handles it well.

Answer (score -1):

As a person who is constantly suggesting edits, I would be happy for the `+2` reputation to be removed. *Unlike others*, I don't purposely edit posts for the reputation.

Users should suggest edits in good will, knowing that they'll be helping others understand the post, rather than "only being in it for the reputation".

Although it had been suggested that users who review the post should be able to contribute to how much reputation the suggester will receive, I am against this as the system will be open to abuse.

Comment: Why post an answer to a several year old question just to restate the content of another answer?

Answer (score -18):

Well, many have already argued about editing useless things like just a thank you or changing the question with the same meaning like this [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258773/user-making-edits-that-arent-edits) and similar to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255644/should-edit-in-edits-be-discouraged). But no one has ever come to a clear consensus.

Moreover, it should be accounted for negative reputation points, but in the end it would be discouraging others from even editing a question let it be meaningful or not.

Comment: From what I've understood, there is a clear consensus that bad edits are a problem. I asked about this, recently: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266637/very-poor-formatting-approved-again The site already accounts that by giving automatic edit bans for accounts that make several bad edits. I just feel that the measure is too slow and kicks in too rarely to make a difference.

Comment: Exactly the SO handles a lot of requests of edits which cannot be handled that fast.The moderator / admin is the final person to approve it or sometimes it automatically gets approved.

Comment: No, it's three approves or three rejects from reviewers - whichever comes first. But I don't see how this is relevant to my suggestion.