# Bad editing (Low quality) by just tags

Tags: discussion, support, suggested-edits

I have basically been reviewing suggested edits and have come across these: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5455640), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5455641), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5455633), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5455635), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5455644), etc., etc.

All by the same user - [CodeSlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3810923/codeslayer). He keeps trying to add the [google-maps-api-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-api-3) tag which I personally think is hinging on the verge of abuse of the editing system just to gain that extra " **+2** ".

What can we do (other than rejecting the edit or posting an "other" with a custom rejection message) to get the user to stop the low-quality edits?

---

Leaning on *@gnuana*'s comment below:

> There is a pretty good discussion happening here
>   [meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267311/1230782](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267311/1230782)

I think that (<sup>*above link*</sup>) is a great alternative that will deter these pointless edits.

I just want to know what we should be doing in the event that we have to constantly deal with these shocking edits.

Comment: If he gets enough rejections he will get an auto ban from the system.

Comment: Looks to me like the right thing is happening. Reviewers have been rejecting the edits as too minor. Would be interesting to hear from a mod if/when this triggers the auto ban @slugster mentions. I'm normally pretty generous with my edit reviews when tags are added, because IMHO it's important for questions to have the right tags. But I would still vote too minor for adding google-maps-api-3 if google-maps is already there. Adding google-maps if it were missing for a Google Maps related question would be a different case.

Comment: @RetoKoradi That is exactly the mentality I had when reviewing each of these edits, I mean it clearly looks like a user hunting for the reputation.

Comment: These things become more and more popular, users "edit" lots of questions for rep. And another trend is to respond to duplicate questions instead of flagging them. Imagine what would be if you would get money instead of rep...

Comment: There is a pretty good discussion happening here http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267311/1230782

Comment: -1: What's with calling someone out in public like this? Needless.

Comment: @AlexandruCimpanu obligatory: http://dilbert.com/strips/comic/1995-11-13/

Comment: Reject them as vandalism!

Comment: Closely related: [Same one letter edit suggested to nearly 60 questions; should I alert a moderator?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289145)

Comment: @PeterMortensen: Was it really necessary to bump this question with such a minor edit?

Answer (score 1):

You should flag one of the questions where that happens and notify a moderator if you think this user is abusing the edit system, the mods then can send him a message telling him that its discouraged to do what he does. That handles the specific situation best.

If I remember correctly you can also @Username him in the comments of a post where he made an edit and notify him of this very discussion here.

You also should participate in that other discussion about the problem at large. That handles the general problem best.