# Same one-letter edit suggested to nearly 60 questions. Should I alert a moderator?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

While in the suggested edit review queue, I noticed the same edit by the same user come up on two different questions. It was a single-letter change to correct a typo in the name of a common programming language.

On a hunch, I checked the user's activity and found nearly 60 suggestions in the past ~30 minutes. After spot-checking at least a dozen, I determined that every one of these suggestions corrected the same typo (and nothing else).

Normally I would approve an edit that corrects a typo; words should be spelled correctly, especially important words like the name of a language, especially in important places like the title of the post. However, this is a clear case of a user querying for some common error and then correcting it in bulk without regard for the overall quality of the post.

This has been discussed in the past; one SO moderator suggested approving the edits in [this 2011 answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116555/254929), another SO moderator suggested rejecting the edits in [this 2012 answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128515/254929) and so on (see "related reading," below). I'm cautious about taking these older opinions at face value, considering [the changes surrounding the removal of the "too minor" rejection reason in 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238039/254929).

I'm not asking whether to accept or reject the edits themselves. I voted to reject many of those pending edits using the custom "causes harm" reason and the explanation:

> Please do not use search to suggest the same small edit in bulk to many questions without thoroughly revising each question as it deserves.

What I want to know is:

1. Should I alert a moderator about this activity? If so, what's the best way—a custom flag on one of the edited questions?
2. Is it appropriate to solicit assistance from other users in chat to reject the remaining pending suggestions?

## Related reading

- [100 edits in one evening. Is it wrong?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276402/2359271)
- [Same pattern of editing which doesn't improve the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288322/2359271)

And on Meta Stack Exchange:

- [Some users gaming the edit system by searching for misspelled words](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83557/254929)
- [What to do about users who search for spelling mistakes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/169183/254929)

Comment: Totally flag it for moderator attention.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226793/should-we-approve-edits-that-just-change-commercial-links-to-example-com/226874#comment743257_226874 taught me that these kinds of edits aren't necessarily unwelcome, but one should wait until 2k+ rep to do them.

Comment: That's annoying. He's not even capitalizing the name of the language correctly...

Comment: Has anyone left a comment to this user suggesting they stop these types of edits?  Or point them to this post or one of the other Meta posts about serial editing?

Comment: @bluefeet Yes, just now.

Comment: @bluefeet - I *thought* I had, but when I checked their answer I commented on, I didn't see it.  Maybe I refreshed instead of posting it, I was doing a lot of refreshing :P

Comment: Related on Meta.SE: [An alert to serial minor edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116509), [Flag a user as "serial minor editor"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/128514), [What to do about users who search for spelling mistakes?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/169183) [There's nothing a mod can really do at the moment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221832), aside from sitting in the queue, waiting for more suggestions and rejecting them.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to this post.  I was unaware that there would be an issue with simple typo edits.  I accidentally searched for "javscript" and when dozens of posts came up with the same typo, I decided to go through and correct as many as I could, thinking it would help others find the posts better.

Comment: @Mike McCaughan I was less interested in correcting everyone's capitalization and was more interested in the language being spelled correctly.

Comment: @BenjaminRay For the record, I asked this to better document site policy, not as any sort of public shaming or witch hunt. That said, LittleBobbyTables' edits following some of your suggestions are great examples to follow in trying to make the best revision possible.

Comment: One of the things that bothers me is when I see Xcode incorrectly capitalized. When I see "XCode" or "xCode", I fix it. So if fixing one or two is good, then why not 60? Editor diversity is something makes the site better.

Comment: @Air Thanks for clarifying. I'll certainly avoid this type of minor spelling edit in the future.

Comment: For you as someone whose edits [don't have to be reviewed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/), @picciano, it's less of an issue, but you're still bumping questions to the front page, and flooding can be annoying, especially if you've only fixed one little thing on an otherwise poor question.

Comment: If the moderation of minor edits is the real issue, then allow minor edits without moderation. It seems unwise to discourage users from improving the content, even in minor ways.

Comment: It sounds like the bigger issue is the fact that such small typo edits bump the question to the front page and flood the moderation queue.  Had I made these same edits over the course of a month, it would probably not have become an issue.

Comment: As for a minor edit bumping to the front page, it seems same logic should apply. Don't have minor edits bump to the front page. I get the concerns, but it should be fixed correctly, rather than preventing an otherwise useful action.

Comment: @BenjaminRay, editing in a single character would still be an issue, because you are not correcting the rest of the things which need editing. When editing a post, you need to take the time to update everything in the post, not just one thing. For instance, fix the capitalization of JavaScript, update grammar, punctuation, etc..

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I find that problematic. An improvement is an improvement. Not fixing *everything* isn't a flaw.

Comment: @hobbs, I concede the word 'everything' was hyperbolic. But certainly it is more helpful to the community if editors' default action is to fix as many things as they can at once? And wouldn't it be better if questions were not thrown into the review queue or bumped to the front page for a single character improvement? We need to have a balance between improvement of questions and utility of the site. For instance, there's obviously a Markdown way to make the word everything above italic. Is it worth my time to go back and update that for the small improvement in comprehensiveness? I think not.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan the person correcting the typo might not have the ability to address anything else, and the next person who comes around to improve technical aspects might not catch the typo. Putting aside review effort for the moment, the best way to improve posts is not to have a minimum standard of edit size, because then you only get an edit if sufficient knowledge and effort come from *one person*.

Comment: @hobbs, I think I see what you're getting at. And you or I were to edit a post to fix a typo (since we both have > 2000 rep), I would have no problem, because most likely I would never know. So I'll concede that without the review effort, minor changes are indeed welcome. But since there is a review effort for users < 2000 rep, I'm left wondering how to balance the desire for typos to be fixed with the burden placed on reviewers (putting aside the bump to the front page).

Comment: Why don't I see anywhere saying what the edit actually is? Surely it makes a difference what edit they're making. Fixing `magneto` to `magento` is something I would have no problem with because it totally changes the nature of the question, while changing `colour` to `color` would make me want to shoot the person.

Comment: Why would you want to reject edits that are correcting mistakes? If someone kept spelling Microsoft as Microsoaft - why not do a bulk search and correct it? Seems like meaningless dither dathering to me.

Comment: @BenjaminRay: Note that there are (well, were when I last looked) quite a lot of questions with the misspelling 'javascipt' (no r).  However, there were quite a number of those questions where the misspelling was the crux of the problem, and simply correcting the spelling in the question would render the question pointless.  I gave up trying to fix them all because of that — several years ago now.

Comment: Oh no, someone's going around *improving* things!?  Get the pitchforks!

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan fair enough I suppose.

Comment: Does it improve the quality of data on the site? Yes. Then the edits are worthwhile, especially if it improves searches via keywords.

Comment: @Ryan: Yes, correcting the spelling of JavaScript is a worthwhile edit, since it improves the quality of the post. OTOH, rarely would such an edit actually add clarity to the post, so it's not a high priority edit. IMHO such edits should be left to people with enough rep to do them without approval, unless the editor can also fix other issues at the same time, since its somewhat wasteful to require 4 people to fix one word in a non-crucial edit. But even then, there's still the issue of flooding the front page if such edits are done in bulk.

Comment: What's the rate limiting on edits under 2k rep? The major downside I can see with not bumping or requiring approval on "minor" edits is that you could, in theory, completely vandalise a post through a series of minor edits if you were so inclined.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: _"editing in a single character would still be an issue, because you are not correcting the rest of the things which need editing. When editing a post, you need to take the time to update everything in the post, not just one thing"_ Total rubbish.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'll answer your specific questions:

> Should I alert a moderator about this activity? If so, what's the best way—a custom flag on one of the edited questions

My feeling on this is it depends. I know, that's kind of a terrible answer from a moderator but here is why I say that.

**Are the edits vandalizing posts?**

If yes, then sure find one of their posts and use a custom flag with links to some edits asking us to research and step in, if needed.

If not and you think this warrants moderator intervention, then flag for a moderator.

Remember that moderators are human exception handlers, meaning we step in where the community cannot. In some of these edit sprees, it's entirely possible that the behavior could be stopped without us getting involved. As I said in [my comment above](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289145/same-one-letter-edit-suggested-to-nearly-60-questions-should-i-alert-a-moderato#comment171415_289145):

> Has anyone left a comment to this user suggesting they stop these types of edits? Or point them to this post or one of the other Meta posts about serial editing?

By contacting the user via a comment, you've got the ability to get their attention much faster than flagging for a moderator.  We've got 1.5k+ flags in the queue and unfortunately, that means that your flag will be buried in the backlog until one of us gets it and can process it. In cases like this, it might be quicker to connect with that user and explain to them why we don't like the edit sprees. If you leave a comment and the behavior continues, then you've still got other options. You could invite the user to chat to discuss what they are doing, etc.

There have been numerous cases that I've seen edit sprees come to an end because the user has been notified by another community member to stop. The edit spree that triggered this question was stopped by pointing the user to this discussion and no moderator was involved.

Can you see why *it depends* comes into play? There are several things that **you as a user** could do before involving a moderator.  Remember, we should only be involved when the community can't handle it themselves. In this case, there are things that you can do to try and fix what is happening.

> Is it appropriate to solicit assistance from other users in chat to reject the remaining pending suggestions?

If you feel that all of these edits are, in fact, harmful and need to be rejected, then sure reach out to other users and ask for their help in reviewing the edits.

Comment: Isn't this asking people to act vigilante when they spot "odd behaviour" by their own definition? Contacting users behaving oddly and asking them what they are up to could lead to confrontation or escalation of simple issues. These issues may be better assessed and/or stopped by an experienced person who has earned the site's trust. When the issue is bulk behaviour of an individual user (as opposed to individual edits, questions, comments, answers), I think that moderation queue should almost always be better.

Comment: @NeilSlater Nope, I'm not at all asking users to be vigilantes with this. I've attempted to clarify my answer. My point is that feel free to flag for a moderator in these cases, but you have tools at your disposal to help curb these types of edit sprees without getting a moderator involved.

Comment: @NeilSlater - To put what bluefeet's saying in a different way: if you have a problem with how your neighbor's dog is pooping in your yard, you might want to politely talk to them about it instead of immediately going to the police. I've seen many of these edit sprees stopped early by a simple, polite comment from someone who disagreed with the edits, without moderators getting involved.

Answer (score 3):

Non-moderator users do not have the toolkit to deal with aggregate behaviour of specific users on the site. We have the ability to deal with *individual* comments, questions, answers, edits.

If you are concerned about a person's general behaviour on the site, and there is not clear guidance for it, ask on meta as you did here.

If based on the answer in meta, the behaviour is considered damaging or unwanted on the site, then *do not contact the user*, simply flag it - use an appropriate standard reason whenever possible (for efficiency), or use *other* describing the issue. It may be a good idea in your description to link the meta post that helped you decide to raise the flag - but not just a link, something like "This too minor edit repeated on many posts, I think the user may need mod attention: `<link>`"

The moderators have the toolkit and trust of the site to deal with it appropriately. You risk stress of confrontation and petty reprisals from users who are willing to stretch the site rules. Besides which, you could be wrong. The chances of calling someone out for anti-social behaviour resolving well in a single person's favour are not high, and not worth the risk.

Collecting some other well-meaning users together to help edit/down-vote or otherwise critique the unwanted behaviour is essentially forming a vigilante group. This could be very unfair to the person being targeted if it turns out the site consensus is *not* against their behaviour.

I guess the above is a meta-meta answer, but I am posting it as an alternative to the "reach out" answer, which I feel could lead to more problems on the site than it will solve.

In this specific case, I would recommend leaving the robo-editor alone, as the overall effect is the improvement in questions. This editor will get some easy badges - that is a separate issue, because we don't ever measure the *quality* of edits other than a binary accept/reject, so neither does the rep system. Requiring that all edits must improve by some undefined non-trivial amount is not the fix to that in my opinion.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that users should not go vigilante. I always find it odd how some users have [self-assigned themselves with the authority to engage with (so-called) robo-reviewers and fix the behaviour of other users without any community concensus.](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58120/please-dont-approve-minor-or-invalid-edits) I like this alternate solution to not indulge in conflicts without the proper tools.

Comment: "simply flag it" -- I think it would be helpful to mention here that falg message would better refer to respective meta post, so that moderator can get to more context and details of the issue (I for one try to _always_ refer to relevant meta posts in flag messages)

Comment: Thanks for your input. For what it's worth, I couldn't care less about the user's badges. What I do think is worth considering is the process by which users learn to contribute better and better edits over a period of time, during which they have the **benefit** of peer review. I think of the +2 rep less as currency or reward than as an indicator of progress toward that point in time when the training wheels come off. Treating this experience like nothing but mechanical data entry circumvents that process, denies the editor of valuable experience and increases the load on the review queue.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like we have a process problem, without any sort of malice from Benjamin, the author of the edits.

The fact that minor edits bump the questions should be addressed. Barring that, I think Benjamin's edits do improve the overall quality of the site by teaching proper capitalization of one of the the most common programming languages in use today.

Comment: [Allow non-bumping minor edits but review them on /review](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122567)

Comment: [These edits had nothing to do with capitalization.](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7545961)