# User spamming edits removing only "Thanks"

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, reputation, rejected-edits

I just rejected multiple edits by a single user since he only removed the "Thanks" or "Thanks in advance" part of any answer. After looking at the users history of reputation change I saw that he got at least 90 reputation points in one day by just performing above said sections.

I know that in general you should not include a "Thanks" in your question. But is that, and only that, enough to justify an edit and in the end grant +2 reputation points to said user? If so, at what point does it start to get a little bit too much? In my opinion getting hundreds of reputation points just by repetitively doing the same thing over and over should be avoided at some point.

[image]

Since I did not come across something like that my questions are:

- Is there already some kind of mechanic preventing this behavior?
- What do you think about this kind of edit spamming?
- Should I reject or approve this kind of edits, even if they occur this often?

Regarding the question [Removing someone else's "Thank you!"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267384/removing-someone-elses-thank-you): A few of these edits may be appropriate or even recommended - my question is regarding the sheer massive amount of these edits in a short period of time.

Comment: Yes, this is not very reasonable.  The core problem is that such a user re-activates a very large number of questions.  They will flood the front page of other users.  Hard to stop him, consider flagging one of the edited questions and ask a moderator to intervene.

Comment: @HansPassant the front page is wildly different for most users (as they take favorite tags plus interesting tags and shuffle them), the only one would be affected is the tag /active page, but then, I doubt he did on a single tag all the way.

Comment: I look at one of the posts in question and the editor did more than just remove thanks.  Obviously 1 post does not make a trend, but it seems that he is at least trying to clean up everything.  I fail to see a problem.

Comment: @psubsee2003: yes, by now he moved on to doing a little bit more than just removing "thanks" and fixing the spelling of "aswell" to "as well". I agree that some of the latest edits actually are reasonable and would definitely get approved by me, but many of the previous ones would not. Some of the edits i rejected had already reject votes of other SO members, therefore they may actually have got rejected and don´t appear on the list.

Comment: First, this is not spam. Second, you can read by "newest" not by "active".

Comment: @tchrist but you may want to see the actual active ones in regards to really active questions with new answers and comments, not edits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there already some kind of mechanic preventing this behavior?

There is no automated mechanism in place to prevent this behavior. You being a member of the community [do have some power to deal with this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289145/same-one-letter-edit-suggested-to-nearly-60-questions-should-i-alert-a-moderato/289165#289165). You can flag one of their posts for moderator explaining the situation and asking us to review it. You can comment on one of the posts they edited asking them to stop-mass editing. You can ping the user asking them into chat to discuss why we don't like mass-edits.

If you think the user isn't making improvements to the posts, then as a reviewer you can reject these edits. "Thanks" on posts are noise and should be removed. However, I don't think anyone should necessarily be hunting to posts to remove it. If you run across it on the site, then sure feel free to remove it and move on.

Comment: I have flagged one post, i have left a comment. What do you mean with "ping the user"? How do I start a chat with specific user? Other than that: thanks for the help!

Comment: @luk2302 not via chat.  You can notify any editor using an `@` comment by commenting on a post they edited.  It won't show up if you start typing, so you have to type the name manually, but via that comment you can invite them into chat.

Comment: Okay, i did that already, lets see if he reacts.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't "spammy" editing behavior. Opening introductions, closing valedictions, and other fluff should be removed from all questions. It may seem like a minor edit, but it is perfectly valid. I remove them any time I see them, even if I'm not specifically looking for them.

If it doesn't add another piece of useful troubleshooting information that can help define a question, it's generally considering extraneous noise and should be removed.

You should remove things such as (but not limited to):

> "I am a noob and did searches on Google and couldn't find anything."
>
> "I am working on this project and it's really kicking my butt."
>
> "This is not a duplicate. I don't think."
>
> "Can anybody help me?"
>
> "Does anyone have a solution?"
>
> "Sorry if this sounds unclear. Thanks! :)"
>
> "P.S.
>   I don't know what information I have to add.
>   If you ask for something I will add it. Sorry."
>
> "Your help would be much appreciated."
>
> "Thanks in advance"
>
> "Thanks, J"

All of the above things add no value to the question and are typically implied.

Additionally, those who consider this editor "hunting for points," this may be true, and it may be borderline acceptable, but **it isn't hurting anything**. They earn 2 points per edit, that is the equivalent of 1/5th an up vote on an answer (and I've seen answers with very little effort get lots of up votes).

The user can only earn up to **1000** reputation with edits and will only earn reputation on edits while under **2000** reputation, at which point they will be able to make these edits without the approval process.

Comment: At least [some of those edits](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7660179) were "too minor" and so (as it called nowadays) "no improvement at all". This editor is clearly hunting for points.

Comment: In other words, the editor is earning their reputation with edits just as someone who is answering questions is earning reputation with their answers, albeit at a slower pace.

Comment: I think that it would be a problem if the editor ignore more egrerious and pressing issues in the post that can be fixed. For a post that is otherwise fine, except for a "thanks" at the end, is fine editing it.

Comment: @MichaelIrigoyen per your last sentence, you may also want to add that a user can only earn up to 1000 rep points via edits.  So it is impossible for someone to edit their way to any significant privileges without contributing to the community in other ways (making good posts that earn upvotes)