# Rejected and edited suggested edit that didn't apply my edit

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

I have tried to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15288725) a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9955864/7598088) which, IMO, had the wrong tag "html-title" which I replaced with "title". Even tough I can agree that it was an old question and that maybe it wasn't to smart to bump it with a edit, I knew that editing the tag would make it easier for future users to find that question, (which has a solution) not only because it was a more used tag but also because it was the correct one as explained in my edit comment.

Now, it was going well with **2 approves**, only missing the last one. But then, out of nowhere, I get instantly **rejected** by [Community ♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) (which I'm pretty sure is a bot) and **rejected and edited** by [Suhaib Janjua](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3240038/suhaib-janjua) (not even making it to 3 rejects because he edited, but still bumping the question with his edit) and then I don't get the tag changed, only a [thanks message removed](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9955864/revisions) (which I didn't removed myself because 1, it wasn't a big deal and 2, I didn't wanted to delete the OP's way of showing gratefulness).

Can I get my tag edit added too please? I don't wanna try to edit it again and get rejected.

I also noticed he has approved 336 edit suggestions and rejected 329 which is a good percentage of rejects. I don't mind if it's 100%, as long as they're correctly placed.

Comment: A better edit there would be just removing the [tag:html-title] tag, without adding the useless [tag:title] tag to it. You're using it as a meta-tag and it serves no purpose being there, which is probably why they rejected your edit.

Comment: @animuson I'm surprised [title] is a thing; looks incredibly vague.

Comment: @animuson, why do you say it's useless? The tag [tag:title] is specifically for the `title` *element* and the `title` *attribute* (this case). Also, is it a meta-tag?

Comment: You think that all 2 of the followers of that tag is actually adding significant visibility to that question?

Comment: Please do not add "thank you notes" to your posts - check out http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions and also make sure to remove such text from questions when you edit (note that just removing thanks, especially  for rep points, is not welcome - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290019/user-spamming-edits-removing-only-thanks)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Things like "thanks" should be removed, and it may be why the reviewer chose Reject & Edit.
The fact that two reviewers Approved it, despite it not removing the "thanks", is exactly the reason why some reviewers choose "Reject & Edit" instead of just "Reject". Too many reviewers blindly Approve everything, so other reviewers use "Reject & Edit" to forcefully reject edits that they consider bad.

As was pointed out by @animuson in comments, the "title" tag isn't particularly useful. It's a textbook case of a meta-tag - a tag that only has meaning in the context of other text.

So - in the future, *do* remove "thanks", "thanks in advance", and other such lines. And consider if a new tag is useful.

Comment: Isn't there a **approve and edit**?

Comment: @J.Vie Yes, there is. In fact, that happened to one of your edits [here](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15286565). But if the reviewer thinks it's a bad edit, they're more likely to use "Reject & Edit".

Comment: What's bad with the tag, have you read it's [info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/title/info)? It's exactly for this type of questions.

Comment: @J.Vie No it's not. The first sentence of the description indicates that. It's just that someone hijacked the tag wiki and dumped a lot of information about HTML into it. In practice, the tag is being used pretty much anywhere the word "title" appears in a program.

Comment: @J.Vie You might want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

Comment: @animuson, I noticed you **approved and edited** [my suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11379529/revisions) on the [tag:title] tag. I'm not disagreeing with you but if you think it shouldn't be used in any question at all, can't you just delete it?

Comment: @J.Vie No, even moderators cannot just delete tags. If a tag is removed from all questions, the system will delete it. We have a process for this, called "burnination".  If you search that term here on MSO, you'll find a lot of information about tags. And about how we deal with bad tags.